# Weird HashTable ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception

Tags: java, hashtable, indexoutofboundsexception

The test testGetBucket() is only not working when the key is greater than 5 characters. Example if any of the puppy names are longer than 5 characters, the test will return an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception for the getBucket method.

```
@Test
    public void testGetBucket() {
        List<Puppy> puppies = getPuppies();
        MyHashTable<String, Puppy> instance = new MyHashTable<>(DefaultCapacity, DefaultLoadFactor);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Puppy puppy = puppies.get(i);
            instance.put(puppy.name, puppy);
            System.out.print(i);
        }

        List<KeyValuePair<String, Puppy>> actual = instance.getBucket(8);
        assertEquals("Size of bucket is three", 3, actual.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < actual.size(); i++) {
            KeyValuePair<String, Puppy> p = actual.get(i);
            if (p.key.equals("Bob")) {
                assertEquals("Bucket contains " + p.value.name, puppies.get(1), p.value);
            } else if (p.key.equals("Francois")) {
                assertEquals("Bucket contains " + p.value.name, puppies.get(5), p.value);
            } else if (p.key.equals("Inigo")) {
                assertEquals("Bucket contains " + p.value.name, puppies.get(8), p.value);
            }
        }

        actual = instance.getBucket(3);
        assertEquals("Size of bucket is Zero", 0, actual.size());

        actual = instance.getBucket(0);
        assertEquals("Size of bucket is 1", 1, actual.size());
        KeyValuePair<String, Puppy> p = actual.get(0);
        assertEquals("Bucket contains " + p.value.name, puppies.get(2), p.value);
    }



public void put(K key, V value)
    {
       remove(key);
       KeyValuePair<K,V> element = new KeyValuePair<K,V>(key, value);
       getBucket(getBucketIndex(key.hashCode())).add(element);
    }


public int getBucketIndex(int hashCode)
    {
        return hashCode % getNumberOfCollisionBuckets();
    }

public List<KeyValuePair<K,V>> getBucket(int bucketIndex)
    {

        return collisionBuckets[bucketIndex];
    }
```

Comment: We don't see `getNumberOfCollisionBuckets()` nor how `collisionBuckets `is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna go on a limb here and say the problem is this part

```
return hashCode % getNumberOfCollisionBuckets();
```

If your naming is any guidance the problem is the hashCode. I have no idea why you decide to go with such a fragile implementation.

When your error is occurring the hashCode must be of a value that will give an result higher than the array's index value after the modulation.

So the way to fix this? Stop relying on the hashCode to do something like getting an array index... That's not it's purpose.